# Conditional replacement if the "correct" value exists

Tags: r, duplicates

My data consists of two variables, an `id` and a corresponding `name`. The `name` can be two things. Either the id or a string of letters.

If there exists a non-numeric name, I need to replace any numeric names with this value.

Data example

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("100", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "104", "105", "100", "106"), 
             name = c("100", "A", "B", "C", "D", "104", "E", "F", "100", "106"), 
             correct_name = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F", "A", "106"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The third column gives the desired result.

I've been messing around with `%in%` and `duplicated` and `group_by`, but been unable to get anywhere.

EDIT: I missed a crucial part - there can be instances of a character name not existing. Updated the example - sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since you have mentioned that there are certain `id` with no `name` to replace in such cases we can modify the `ave` option, check the condition and replace the values all in one call.

```
df$name <- with(df, ave(name, id, FUN = function(x) {
   inds = grepl("[0-9]+", x)
   if (any(!inds)) 
    replace(x, inds, x[which.max(!inds)])
   else
    x
}))

df
#    id name correct_name
#1  100    A            A
#2  100    A            A
#3  101    B            B
#4  102    C            C
#5  103    D            D
#6  104    E            E
#7  104    E            E
#8  105    F            F
#9  100    A            A
#10 106  106          106
```

---

**Original Answer**

Assuming every `id` would have only one unique `name`, using `dplyr` we can do double `replace` first we change the names which has a number in it to `NA` and then replace those `NA`s with the first non-NA value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(name = replace(name, grepl("[0-9]+", name), NA), 
         name = replace(name, is.na(name), name[!is.na(name)][1]))

#  id   name  correct_name
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#1 100   A     A           
#2 100   A     A           
#3 101   B     B           
#4 102   C     C           
#5 103   D     D           
#6 104   E     E           
#7 104   E     E           
#8 105   F     F           
#9 100   A     A
```

---

And using the same logic with base R `ave`

```
#Replace the numbers with NA
df$name[grepl("[0-9]+", df$name)] <- NA

#Change the NA's to first non-NA value in the group
df$name <- with(df,ave(name, id, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]))
```

---

Another option is to use `tidyr` `fill` in both the directions

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(name = replace(name, grepl("[0-9]+", name), NA)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(name) %>%  #default direction is "down"
  fill(name, .direction = "up")

#  id    name  correct_name
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#1 100   A     A           
#2 100   A     A           
#3 100   A     A           
#4 101   B     B           
#5 102   C     C           
#6 103   D     D           
#7 104   E     E           
#8 104   E     E           
#9 105   F     F
```

PS - I just added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your data.frame call to make the columns as character.

Comment: What does the `[1]` do?

Comment: @NelsonGon  there can be more than 1 `name` which can be non-NA in each group but we can replace it with only 1 value hence we subset it and select the first non-NA value from each group.

Comment: Nice. How do we ensure we don't duplicate what we're replacing with?

Comment: that's what the assumption is. There would be the same `name` value for each `id`

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `dplyr` and the use of `ifelse` plus `grepl` with the pattern set to `"\\d+"` (ie: digits).

Edit: it's possible to have just one `mutate`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(namenew = ifelse(
    grepl("\\d+", name),   # match for digits in the string
    name[!grepl("\\d+", name)][1], # if TRUE, substitute with the first non-digit
    name # if FALSE, keep it
  )) 
#    id name correct_name namenew
# 1 100  100            A       A
# 2 100    A            A       A
# 3 101    B            B       B
# 4 102    C            C       C
# 5 103    D            D       D
# 6 104  104            E       A
# 7 104    E            E       E
# 8 105    F            F       F
# 9 100  100            A       A
```

---

Maybe more clear of what's happening compared to my solution above. (Similar to @Ronak Shah)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(namenew = ifelse(
    grepl("\\d+", name), 
    NA,
    name
  )) %>% 
  mutate(namenew = ifelse(
    is.na(namenew),
    namenew[!is.na(namenew)][1],
    namenew
  ))


#    id name correct_name namenew
# 1 100  100            A       A
# 2 100    A            A       A
# 3 101    B            B       B
# 4 102    C            C       C
# 5 103    D            D       D
# 6 104  104            E       A
# 7 104    E            E       E
# 8 105    F            F       F
# 9 100  100            A       A
```

Data (`stringsAsFactors` is important):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("100", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "104", "105", "100"), 
                 name = c("100", "A", "B", "C", "D", "104", "E", "F", "100"), 
                 correct_name = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F", "A"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast dirty way:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
  if (is.na(as.numeric(df$id[x]))==FALSE){
    ind=which(df$id==df$id[x])
    ind2=which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character((df$name[ind]))))==TRUE)
    df$name[x]<<-df$name[ind[ind2[1]]]
  }
})
df
   id name correct_name
1 100    A            A
2 100    A            A
3 101    B            B
4 102    C            C
5 103    D            D
6 104    E            E
7 104    E            E
8 105    F            F
9 100    A            A
```

Convert names to `numeric`. If `NA` appears, name is letter. If not, it is number. Iterate over other names with same `id` and assign letter found in other sample with same `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can be solved by an *update join* using a *look-up table*:

The look-up table is created by filtering `df` for non-digit entries:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!name %like% "^\\d+$"]
```

> ```
>     id name correct_name
> 1: 100    A            A
> 2: 101    B            B
> 3: 102    C            C
> 4: 103    D            D
> 5: 104    E            E
> 6: 105    F            F
> ```

Now, `df` is joined with the look-up table and where matches are found, `name` is replaced by the respective entry in the look-up table. Otherwise, `name` remains unchanged:

```
setDT(df)[df[!name %like% "^\\d+$"], on = "id", name := i.name]
df
```

> ```
>      id name correct_name
>  1: 100    A            A
>  2: 100    A            A
>  3: 101    B            B
>  4: 102    C            C
>  5: 103    D            D
>  6: 104    E            E
>  7: 104    E            E
>  8: 105    F            F
>  9: 100    A            A
> 10: 106  106          106
> ```

Comment: actually went with a similar solution in the end - but not quite as neat as this.